# How to restrict Asp.net Web API / Owin discovery of controllers by namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

In the same project, I have two similar startup classes like this :

```
namespace X.A
{
    public class AStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.EnsureInitialized();

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace X.B
{
    public class BStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.EnsureInitialized();

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have several controllers, some are in namespace X.A... :

```
namespace X.A.SomePlace
{
    [RoutePrefix("A/SomeRouting")]
    public class Controller1 : ApiController
    {
        [Route("SomeMethod")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(SomeMethodResponse))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetParameters([FromBody] SomeMethodRequest request)
        {
            // Some code
        }
    }
}
```

... and others are in namespace X.B...:

```
namespace X.B.SomeOtherPlace
{
    [RoutePrefix("B/AnotherRouting")]
    public class Controller2 : ApiController
    {
        [Route("AnotherMethod")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(AnotherMethodResponse))]
        public IHttpActionResult AnotherMethod([FromBody] AnotherMethodRequest request)
        {
            // Another code
        }
    }
}
```

...and all controllers are in the same Asssembly.

Currently, all controllers get automagically registered to both API.
I would like to restrict the controller discovery by namespace (i.e. AStartup registers all controllers from X.A.... and BStartup registers all controllers from X.B...)

Is there a way to do this with MapHttpAttributeRoutes?

I would be also happy with another method that does not use attribute routes (i.e. if you have a method where I have to explicitely registers each controller programatically, that would work fine for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on peco answer, I've found the whole list of WEB API Services here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api

The answer was to implement a custom IHttpControllerTypeResolver which is succinctly described at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection.

I also found a lot of inspiration at http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/

In case this is useful for someone else, here is the IHttpControllerTypeResolver I used:

```
namespace X.A
{
    public class AControllerTypeResolver : DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver
    {
        public AControllerTypeResolver() : base(IsHttpEndpoint)
        {
        }

        private static bool IsHttpEndpoint(Type t)
        {    
            if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("t");

            return t.IsClass &&
                t.IsVisible &&
                !t.IsAbstract &&
                typeof(ABaseController).IsAssignableFrom(t);
        }
    }
}
```

And I did the same for BControllerTypeResolver.

I did Replace the default service in AStartup like this:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new AControllerTypeResolver());
```

I also had to make sure all my controllers are deriving from ABaseController (respectively BBaseController).

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how to do that with attribute routes. But if you want to use normal routes you can implement a custom `IAssembliesResolver` (the default one scans all the assemblies in the current appdomain for controllers).

```
public class CustomAssemblyResolver : IAssembliesResolver
{
    private readonly Assembly[] _assemblies;

    public CustomAssemblyResolver(params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        _assemblies = assemblies;
    }

    public ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        return _assemblies;
    }
}
```

And then for example in your `AStartup` you could use this like so:

```
public class AStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new CustomAssemblyResolver(typeof(Controller1).Assembly));

        config.EnsureInitialized();

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: The various controllers have distinct namespaces but are all in the same assembly (will update question to reflect this). Do you think it's still possible to use a CustomAssemblyResolver to achieve this filtering?

Comment: Hm, not sure. Is there a reason they can't be in different assemblies?

Answer (score 2):

Ramsey's answer that built off of peco's structure worked for me.

In my case, I had a hosting MVC/api project with multiple OWIN app.map'd class library web.api projects.  I think the standard

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

was causing conflicting routes to try to be registered between the different api projects.  Now each OWIN api and the hosting app's api all have their own BaseApiController within their namespaces that they inherit from.  Each BaseApiController has Ramsey's ControllerTypeResolver.  OWIN projects do their own WebApiConfig setup, but now the attribute route registration looks like this:

```
    apiConfig.Services.Replace(typeof(System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new Core.Api.Controllers.RestrictedControllerTypeResolver());
apiConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

I tested this and now when each project executes the MapHttpAttributeRoutes it is only mapping routes for controllers within its own project.

Thanks everyone!